# Limit of Form Recognizer users has been reached?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am currently running an Form Recognizer instance. A colleague of mine also wants to take a look at the Form Recognizer but he sent me [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/form-recognizer-container-howto). There it says "The limit for Form Recognizer container users has been reached. We are not currently accepting new applications for the Form Recognizer container." Is this correct or is the documentation outdated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct for the current FR v1 containers release. Please use the Form Recognizer cloud service currently - https://aka.ms/form-recognizer, we will be releasing the Form Recognizer v2.1 containers shortly.

Neta - MSFT